# Why is my C# class telling me there's no constructor with zero arguments?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public class TestService : BaseService, IDisposable
{
    public TestService(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
    }
    public IRepository<Exam> Exams { get { return GetStandardRepo<Exam>(); } }

}
```

and

```
public class BaseService : IDisposable
{
    public BaseService(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        CreateDbContext();

        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why there's an error on the first class saying "Base Service does not take a constructor with zero arguments" ?

Comment: Because `BaseService` doesn't have a constructor with zero arguments. It has one with a single argument.

Comment: Be default the compiler can call only the parameter less constructor of the base class else you will have to add that call manually

Answer (score 7):

You need to call your base constructor:

```
public TestService(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider) : base(repositoryProvider)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `IRepositoryProvider` to the `BaseService` constructor by chaining it:

```
public class TestService : BaseService, IDisposable
{
    public TestService(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider) : 
           base(repositoryProvider)
    {
    }
    public IRepository<Exam> Exams { get { return GetStandardRepo<Exam>(); } }
}
```

Since you have not done so, it is interpreted as trying to initialize `BaseService` using a parameterless constructor, which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the base constructor of BaseService. Change your implementation like this:

```
public class TestService : BaseService, IDisposable
{
    public TestService(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    : base(repositoryProvider)
    {
    }
    public IRepository<Exam> Exams { get { return GetStandardRepo<Exam>(); } }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the base class does not contain a parameter less constructor i.e. a constructor which takes 0 arguments.

When the constructor of this derived class is called it will call the parameter less constructor of the base class as there is no explicit call to the constructor of the base class and since there is no parameter less constructor in the base class the above error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Because the constructor in `TestService` will try to call `BaseService` with no argument.

fix:

```
public TestService(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider): base(repositoryProvider){ }
```